# The Largest Piece of Circumference

Tags: pr.probability, geometric-probability

We add $n$ random lines to the unit disc. We do so by adding two points on the disc, transcribing a line between them and extending that line to the boundary of the disc, namely the unit circle. Each line is chosen independently and we do this $n$ times.

After $n$ random lines have been added, what is the probability that the largest arc on the unit circle between two points is of length $\pi/2$ or longer? To be clear, the arc itself must not have any points on it.

Comment: You might find the following easier and suggestive.  Pick a specific quadrant of the circle.  Compute that area A of the disk with the following property: for any point P in the area, at least half the disk is comprised of points Q such that PQ intersects the quadrant. I imagine A is at least a quarter of the disk.  Now the goal is to avoid the area, and when in the area, to avoid the region of points Q. This should give something like (1-area/2)^n as an upper bound for your probability.  Gerhard "Tackle The Problem In Halves" Paseman, 2017.10.20.

Comment: what is here  "a piece of circumference on the circle" ? does it mean, one  of the 2n arcs into which the circumference is divided by the 2n points?

Comment: I will point out that the tag (discrete-mathematics) is deprecated - see [the tag-info](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/discrete-mathematics/info) - so it would be good to choose some other suitable tag for the question.

Answer (score 7):

The distribution of the maximal distance between a pair of random points on the circle is known - when you scale it by $n/\log n$ you get a [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution) with scale 1, location 1., see, e.g.,

*Schlemm, Eckhard*, [**Limiting distribution of the maximal distance between random points on a circle: a moments approach**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.spl.2014.05.019), Stat. Probab. Lett. 92, 132-136 (2014). [ZBL1294.60045](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1294.60045).

so it is quite obvious the the probability of maximal distance being $O(1)$ goes to zero exponentially fast (it is obvious that it goes to zero about as fast as $(3/4)^{2n}$, in fact.

Comment: So quite researchy after all then!

Comment: I guess the last bit is to prove that extrapolating a line from two end points chosen randomly inside the unit circle to the unit circle itself results in points that are themselves uniformly random. Apart from what might be a misguided belief that this is obvious, I can only suggest constructing those points from a basic geometric calculation given the end points of the line stated in polar coordinates. I'm guessing it should all just fall out.

Answer (score 4):

To re-ask Pietro Majer's question, what do you mean by a "piece of circumference"?

---

[image: CircChords]

          

<sup>$20$ random points, $n=10$ chords.</sup>

---

If you mean the largest section of the circumference containing no chord points,
then the chords play no role: the question could be posed just in terms of
$n$ (or $2n$) points, rather than $n$ "lines."
On the other hand, every chord of the circle has half the circumference to one
side or the other.

---

**Added**.
I think James Smith's interpretation of the question makes the most sense:

---

[image: RandLines]

          

<sup>$10$ random points inside the circle, determining $n=5$ lines. Largest arc: $94^\circ$.</sup>

---

Comment: OP is choosing two points *in* the circle, not *on* the circle, when drawing the lines, so it's not clear to me that the chords give the same answer as choosing points on the circle.

Comment: I agree, I think it's two points inside the circle, not on the circumference. I also think 'piece of circumference' means [arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_(geometry)). The OP really needs to clear this confusion up!

Comment: @JamesSmith: Your interpretation makes sense.

Comment: Okay, emboldened by your comment I've edited the question, so let's see. I actually think it's quite interesting although not very researchy.